# jQuery.getScript() in bookmarklet proceeds to callback, but does not execute plugin successfully

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, bookmarklet, dom-manipulation

I have a problem with creating a tool that's provides a custom overlay on a page via a code generation plugin that is grabbed from the server once the user clicks a bookmarklet on an external site.

When calling `$.getScript` inside the bookmarklet, the bookmarklet gets the script successfully and starts executing the callback function. Everything is working until I start accessing the plugin itself to start generating the HTML. However, once the plugin method is called, I am unable to receive anything from console, and the overlay fails to appear.

Plugin structure (source for methods themselves omitted as it's a company project - unfortunate, I'm aware, but sadly necessary).:

```
(function(jQuery){

    var methods = {
        generateHeader : function () {

        },
        generateItem : function(arguments) {

        },
        generateGridList : function(arguments) {

        },
        hideOverlay : function(){

        }
    }

    jQuery.fn.generator = function(method) {
        console.log("generator reached"); //Doesn't print.
        if(methods[method]){
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method[method] === 'object' || !method){
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.generator');
        }
    };

})( jQuery );
```

And my relevant bookmarklet contents:

```
$.getScript(<scriptURL>, function() {

    //generate data to send to server   

    //send unordered lists to server for processing
    $.ajax({
        requestType:'GET',
        url: <url>,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'callback',
        success: function(returnedData){
            //success param inside as data is required to proceed.
            $.each(returnedData.data, function(i, val){
                var htmlToAdd,
                content;

                console.log(val); //succeeeds, not null.

                htmlToAdd = $.generator('generateItem', val);

                console.log(htmlToAdd); //fails to reach log at this point

                //code to append to page
            });
        }
    });
});
```

All the methods do is generate HTML and CSS based on $.css and $(), var.append() and var.html()  functions, and a couple of hide/remove functions to clear it on exit.

It's late here (close to 9:30pm as of posting) and I'm losing concentration, so I'll be double checking the methods when I arrive in the office tomorrow morning, I just wanted clarification on any pitfalls this approach has, or if I have any glaring mistakes in my AJAX request, my use of getScript() or my plugin structure. If I know it's likely to be a method based issue, that narrows my search and allows for a potential rewrite of certain functions.

Thanks in advance,

Craig Domville.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just wanted clarification on any pitfalls this approach has, or if I have any glaring mistakes in my AJAX request, my use of getScript() or my plugin structure.

I see nothing wrong with your basic approach.

Some things to consider: Before you use `$.generator(...)`, add `console.log($.generator)` and see if it returns the function code you expect. Don't assume that just because getScript  callback fired, that script was executed properly. You seem to assume that $ == jQuery; maybe that is a safe assumption, maybe not.

Comment: Replaced $ with jQuery in the appropriate places to elmiminate confusion (including in the plugin). It seems that the plugin isn't loaded, because the console.log shows it as 'undefined'. Thanks for the spot. Now to work out why it's not loading.